# Print images c#.net

Tags: c#, image, printing, picturebox

I have an image in a PictureBox, and I want to print it. No formatting, no nothing, just print it.

I've been searching on Google but I've got nothing, only people printing forms or text or reports.

```
private string imgSrc;

    public string ImgSrc
    {
        get { return imgSrc; }
        set { imgSrc = value; }
    }

    public Id_Manager()
    {
        ImgSrc = "D:\\Foto.jpg";

        InitializeComponent();
        idPicture.Load(this.ImgSrc);
    }
```

Obviously the image is going to change, but for now I'm just interested in printing that image. I'm saving the url in a property just in case. Any help?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The Code below uses the PrintDocument object which you can place an image on to the printdocument and then print it.

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
...
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
    pd.Print();       
}

private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D:\\Foto.jpg");
    Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);     
}
```

Comment: on the last line, it should be "img", not "ing" :-)

Comment: do NOT forget to dispose the "img" on printPage(...) otherwise, you'll be stuck on the second printing with IOException :-)

Answer (score 13):

Using the location, I have this FileInfo extension method that does it:

```
public static void Print(this FileInfo value)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = value.FullName;
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
    p.Start();
}
```